# Custom Icon for Select Drop Down based on value reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, select

I am new to `react`. I am using `ANT JS` library. Here,I am using `Ant js Select`.

Here's my `select` code which looks like this

```
<div>
    <Form.Item label="Choose  Configuration" >
        {getFieldDecorator('select', {
            valuePropName: 'option',
            rules: [{ required: true }],
            onChange: (value) => { this.onConfigNameChange(value) },
             />

        })(
            <Select  mode="single" placeholder="Please select Configuration"  >
                {
                    this.state.dbConfigList.map((dbConfig) => (
                        <Option value={JSON.stringify(dbConfig)}>{dbConfig.name}</Option>
                    ))
                }
            </Select>
        )}
    </Form.Item>
</div >
```

In the dbConfigList, I have the object which looks like this.

> ```
> (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> 0: {id: 1, name: "first config", data: "{"host":"localhost","type":"elastic"}"}
> 1: {id: 2, name: "second config", data: "{"host":"129.242.3.3","type":"mysql"}"}
> 2: {id: 3, name: "third config", data: "{"host":"192.168.12.1","type":"mongo"}"}
> 3: {id: 4, name: "fourth config", data: "{"host":"localhost","type":"mysql"}"}
> ```

I will display the `name` in the drop-down `select` option as shown in the code above. Based on the `name`, I want to take the `type` from the `data` in the object. Next, I want to display the `icon` based on the type into the select drop-down list with the `name` attached to it.

Here's what i tried,

```
<Select  mode="single" placeholder="Please select Configuration"  >
    {
        this.state.dbConfigList.map((dbConfig) => (
            <Option value={JSON.stringify(dbConfig)}><Icon icon="database" iconSize={20} color="violet" />{dbConfig.name}</Option>
        ))
    }
</Select>
```

I passed the `icon` inside the Option. And it displayed like the image below,
[image: output i got(image)]

I don't want the same color. I want to make icon color based on the type. 
Like `green` for `mysql`, `violet` for `elastic` and `grey` for `mongo`. I don't know how to make it possible. So how to make custom icon for value in select. I searched stack overflow but can't find any answers. Help me with some solutions.

Required Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define map of color like:

```js
   const colorMap = {
      mysql : "green",
      elastic : "violet",
      mongo:"grey"
}
```

and use that:

```js
<Select  mode="single" placeholder="Please select Configuration"  >
    {
        this.state.dbConfigList.map((dbConfig) => {
            var dbData = JSON.parse(dbConfig.data);
            return (
            <Option value={JSON.stringify(dbConfig)}>
                <Icon ... color={colorMap[dbData.type] || "red"} />{dbConfig.name}
            </Option>)
        })
    }
</Select>
```

Comment: Thanks.. But the `data` is in the form of string. How to JSON parse the data and get the type from it.

Comment: Is there a problem with `JSON.parse(dbConfig)` ?

Comment: @ Auticcat, I can't get the type from the data.`dbConfig.data.type`. It come as empty.

Comment: @Kiddy you can use ```var dbData = JSON.parse(dbConfig.data)``` and access type with ```dbData.type```

Comment: @tunapq,  but where to put the JSON.parse. If i created a new dbdata, then how to map it to select. I mapped select with dbconfig list. how to use dbdata in it

Comment: @Auticcat, No problem, but where to use it in select

Answer (score 0):

You could include color as an attribute to the objects in the dbConfigList: just like you have host and type add color. 
Then in your select code you have it this way:

```
<Select  mode="single" placeholder="Please select Configuration"  >
{
    this.state.dbConfigList.map((dbConfig) => (
        <Option value={JSON.stringify(dbConfig)}><Icon icon="database" iconSize={20} color={dbConfig.color} />{dbConfig.name}</Option>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the color in the data. The `data` is in the form of string. How to JSON parse the `data` and get the color from it.

Comment: could you post the new dbConfig list?

Comment: `(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "first config", data: "{"host":"localhost","type":"elastic", "color":"blue"}"}
1: {id: 2, name: "second config", data: "{"host":"129.242.3.3","type":"mysql","color":"green"}"}
2: {id: 3, name: "third config", data: "{"host":"192.168.12.1","type":"mongo","color":"grey"}"}
3: {id: 4, name: "fourth config", data: "{"host":"localhost","type":"mysql","color":"green"}"}`

Comment: Here data is in the form of string

Comment: dbConfig[0].data.color should return blue. try displaying this on your console to make sure you are able to get the color attribute first. also, i think its already a string so no need for conversion. the trick is to ensure you are actually getting a value for color